# Problems when sending emails with attachments via Gmail API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

we created a GCP project which uses the "gmail.send" scope and the app was verified by Google. We can now send emails just fine but when we send attachments (eg. a PDF file) when the email arrives to myself (the authenticated user) it has the attachments, when it arrives to someone else there are no attachments. I noticed that in my 'Sent' folder the outbound email is stored with all the attachments regardless. It seems Google is mysteriously deleted the attachments depending on the recipient. Any ideas what could have caused this and how to fix it? The code is in Ruby and we're using the Gmail API.

Comment: Use a service like mailtrap.io to debug sending emails. On StackOverflow include your code and the received mail message with headers (redacted) otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Please provide more details. Which product are you using (app engine)? How did you configure this app? So the recipient doesn't have an attachment but in the sent folder you can see an email with attachment? It's all type of attachments (txt, zip, pdf, csv, etc.)?